# Map View in R: Labelling Name for Polygon in Map

Tags: r, polygon, labeling, choropleth

I have created following choropleth map for cropland.

[image]

The code I used is:-

```
library(mapview)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
setwd("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/IEM")
Province3Miscellaneous<-st_read("BagmatiProMiscellaneous.shp")
Province3Miscellaneous
View(Province3Miscellaneous)
Province3Miscellaneous<-st_set_crs(Province3Miscellaneous,'+init=EPSG:4326')
Province3Miscellaneous
View(Province3Miscellaneous)
mapview(Province3Miscellaneous, zcol="CULTI", col.region=colorRampPalette
    (c("goldenrod","goldenrod1","goldenrod2","goldenrod3","goldenrod4")))
```

The attribute table of the map data is:-
[image]

However, I want the district name of each polygon to be displayed on the choropleth map. Is that possible in choropleth map? If yes, How?

Comment: How do you want it displayed? Do you want all the names to be visible all the time over the polygons they represent, like `geom_sf_label` does with a `ggplot` graphic, or do you want it visible on hover or click over the region?

Comment: @Spacedman, I want all the names to be visible all the time over polygons with basemap  as shown above .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the labels and the label options like this:

```
mapview(d, zcol="Z", label=d$CNTR_CODE, 
   labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = TRUE, textOnly = TRUE))
```

Where `d` is my spatial data frame coloured by column "Z" and "CNTR_CODE" column has my label names in.

Leave out the `textOnly=TRUE` to change the style.